# python imagedownloader, not working in other files as class

Tags: python, imagedownload

This is my first program, it's an "imagedownloader" with user input for the width and height.
When I run my Code in a single File, without making a Class, it works. But after trying to make it as a Class and import it to the Main file, it doesn't work anymore, but there is no Error.
This is how I imported the Module and created an Object.

Main file:

```
from DownLoader import *

d = DownLoader("https://imga.biz/", 40, 40)

d.down()
```

Donwloader module :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO



class DownLoader:
    def __init__(self, url_, xx, yz):
        self.url = url_
        self.x = xx
        self.y = yz
        self.page = requests.get(self.url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page.text, "html.parser")
        self.images = self.soup.find_all("img")
        self.images_src_array = []
        self.src_old = ""
        for i in self.images:
            if i['src'][0:4] == "http": #check if its a https site
                if i['src'] == self.src_old: #whether is the same image as last
                    continue
                else:
                    self.images_src_array.append(i['src'])
                    self.src_old = i['src']

    def down(self):
        name = ""
        index = 0
        for img in self.images_src_array:
            if self.check_image_size(img)[0] >= self.x and self.check_image_size(img)[1] >= self.y:
                img_data = requests.get(img).content
                with open(name + str(index) + ".jpg", 'wb') as handler:
                    handler.write(img_data)
                    print(str(index) + " : " + img)
                    index += 1


    def check_image_size(self, url):
        try:
            img_data = requests.get(url).content
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
            return img.size
        except Exception:
            return (0, 0)
```

downloader without Class or import, that im trying to convert in to a Class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = input("Enter Url: ")
x = int(input("insert width: "))
y = int(input("insert height: "))
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
images = soup.find_all("img")
images_src_array = []
src_old = ""

for src in images:
    if src['src'][0:4] == "http": #check if its a https site
        if src['src'] == src_old: #whether is the same image as last
            continue
        else:
            images_src_array.append(src['src'])
            src_old = src['src']


def download(images_src, width, height):
    name = ""
    index = 0
    for img in images_src:
        if check_image_size(img)[0] >= width and check_image_size(img)[1] >= height: #checks size and also if its image
            img_data = requests.get(img).content
            with open(name+str(index)+".jpg", 'wb') as handler:
                handler.write(img_data)
                print(str(index) + " : " + img)
                index += 1


def check_image_size(url_link):
    try:
        data = requests.get(url_link).content
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
        return img.size
    except Exception:
        return (0,0) #return for height and width


download(images_src_array, x, y)

print("\nfinish")
page.close()
```

Comment: Show how you created an instance of your class `DownLoader` and then how you called the `down` method of the instance. Also, show how you imported the module.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, i edited my post

Comment: Print out `d.images_src_array` to see if you found anything to download.

Comment: print(d.images_src_array)
[ ]

on the bottom i added the code without a class

Comment: on an different website it seems to work..

Comment: You're running both versions on the same machine, right? If `print(d.images_src_array)` shows you `[ ]` then you'll need to see what's in `self.images`.

Comment: still empty.

After adding an User Agent for the requests module, it show the jpg url with print(self.images)
but it still unable to download an image.

Comment: now im able to download the image, but the format is not supportet. i tryed .jpg/.png/.jpeg

Comment: Do `response = requests.get(image_url)` then you can query the content type via `response.headers['Content-Type']` to see what's being returned.